# Alineación de 4 divs en 2 columnas con contenido aparte y z-index. HTML | CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

**Update (Actualización más abajo!).**

Estoy realizando esta alineación de *divs* con respecto a un contenido aparte que esta posicionada detrás de los *divs* que quiere alinear:

**Me explico:**

**Div principal:** Este div tiene oculto otro div que se desplaza con una pequeña animación con **jQuery**, si pulsas en la flecha blanca se desplaza su contenido (que es el otro div), igualmente si quieres cerrarlo se oculta si vuelves a pulsar. En Realidad uso Z-index para poder manejar estos 2 elementos.

[image: DIV 1]
[image: Div desplazado]

**Ahora me gustaría lograr algo como lo que les muestro en la siguiente imagen.** La cosa es poder posicionar los recuadros tanto el como el con el div con el contenido (siendo este le que esta detrás).

Realmente he logrado posicionar los 2 primeros recuadros, pero cuando voy a colocar otros 2 en la siguiente fila, se me descuadran y se desacomoda todo, he intentado colocarlos con contenedor individuales pero no resulta.

[image: logro]
Estructura HTML:

```
      <section>
             <h2>Services</h2>
        <div id="contain" class="contenedor">
            <div class="contenedorICON">
                    <div class="icon" id="Wirefrime">       
    <i class="fas fa-ruler-horizontal"></i>
                </div>
<div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-sort-down" class="animate"></i>
        </div>
                <div class="contenedorp">   
                    <div class="parrafo">
                        <h4>Wirefrime</h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam fugiat quisquam asperiores autem tempore.
                    </div>
                    </div>              
        </div> 
        <div class="contenedorICON"> 
                <div class="icon" id="Web-Design">
                                <i class="fas fa-ruler-horizontal" id="iconD"></i>
                </div>
       <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-sort-down" class="animate"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="contenedorp">
                    <div class="parrafo">
                        <h4>Web design</h4>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam fugiat quisquam asperiores autem tempore.
                    </div>                          
                    </div>              
                </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

CSS:

```
.icon {
    text-align: center;
    height: 183px;
    width: 51%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    position: absolute;
}
#contain {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 36px;
    height: 99%;
    width: 72%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.contenedorICON {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 35%;
    left: 82px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.contenedorp {
    position: relative;
    width: 91%;
    top: 4px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: -72px;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}
.parrafo {
    width: 55%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(208, 130, 30) , rgb(208, 66, 10));
    padding: 27px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 13px;
    top: 16px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 32%;
}
.arrow {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 29px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: translateX(-55%);
    width: 67px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 585;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 44px;
    left: 100px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Alguno usuario de este foro, podria orientarme a como hacerlo? Igualmente acepto sugerencias del código por que no se si mi idea sea la mas correcta para hacerlo.

Gracias!

**Update:** Pude acomodar los divs, gracias a la sugerencia del usuario pero ahora tengo un pequeño problema con el posicionamiento de los items con z-index

**Mi nueva estructura HTML (resumida):** La clase grid-container es una clase que envuelve a todo el contenido que tengo dentro de las siguientes clases, que son los cuatro recuadros con sus respectivos contenidos posicionados *detras* de los principales.

```
<div  class="grid-container"> <!--Contenedor envolvente-->

              <div class="grid-item"> <!--Contenedor principal-->
<i class="fas fa-ruler-horizontal"></i>
<div class="arrow1"> <!--Contenedor para icono, aca establezco un color para cada uno-->
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>

    <div class="contain-child"> <--!Contenedor para los parrafos.-->

        <div class="grid-item-child">2</div> <!--Hijos-->

        </div>

           </div>
           </div>
```

[image: Ahora]

Ahora cuando hago la animación (consta de desplazar el div lentamente). con mi funcion jquery, el div con la clase (contain-child) se superpone al div principal y lo que quiere es que se ponga detras del contenedor naranja.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le doy a la flecha para ocultar el parrafo, este si lo hace

En este punto el div se empiza a subir, ocultandose detras del recuadro naranja.

[image: imagen]

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 170px);
    padding: 30px;
    grid-gap: 73px 157px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
.grid-item {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 218px;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(208, 130, 30) , rgb(208, 66, 10));
    border-radius: 12px;
Z-index: 99;
}
.grid-item-child {
    width: 217px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(1596, 223, 167, 0.88) , rgba(149, 45, 40, 0.66));
    border-radius: 11px;
}
.contain-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
        transition: 0.5s;
}
```

¿`opacity` podría ser un opción para esto? o alguna especie de efecto toggle.

Aun no he encontrado como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>   
</div>




.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 170px);
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 30px;
   grid-gap: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;

  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Recuerda que no es solo publicar código, además es muy bien visto que agregues una explicaciòn

Comment: Amigo carlos buenas noches, gracias a tu sugerencia pude acomodar mi codigo y adecuarlo pero ahora tengo una cuestion  con los z-index. Puedes ver mi actulizacion mas arriba.